# DataTables Ajax not executing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable

I am using DataTables version `1.10.2`.  I am dealing with thousands of data sets so I am using server side processing.  I cannot even get the file to run via ajax.  I am trying to run the file with test.php which is shown below.

```
<?php file_put_contents("itworked.txt","itworked"); ?>
```

I have attempted to create the DataTable with the following tactics, however the file is never created.  If I visit the link through a browser then the file is created.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#playertimes').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "http://domain.com/HCP/plugins/plugin_Timer/assets/php/test.php" 
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#playertimes').dataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "http://domain.com/HCP/plugins/plugin_Timer/assets/php/test.php" 
  });
});
```

Why is the file not being called?

Comment: Have you tried using a relative path to your test.php file (fe. don't include `http://domain.com`).

Comment: Yes but I am not sure if its actually hitting the file

Comment: Better way to test if its being hit would be using the `syslog` function (fe. `syslog(LOG_INFO, date() . ": test.php");`).  That takes file permissions out of the question.

Comment: Also, accessing your web browser's development console to look at XHR or Network events should be sufficient.

Comment: I have looked at the web console and there is no XHR requesst, not even an attempt with failure

Comment: Any comments?  Why is it not even running an ajax request?

Comment: Only thing I can think is it expects a relative ajax path (not including domain).  I suppose you can try to call `.api().ajax.reload()` on the returned from `$().dataTable()`.

Comment: Doesn't Work :( I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should read the documentation for datatable 1.10.
some changes where made, thought there is still backward compatibility but i think your should stick with the one of 1.10 upward..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#playertimes').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "http://domain.com/HCP/plugins/plugin_Timer/assets/php/test.php" 
  });
});
```